# Can't install R package from the source

Tags: r, installation

I am trying to install old version of xgboost (or any other) lib from the link or local folder and every time I face this message

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/xgboost/xgboost_0.4-1.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Then goes

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xgboost'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.5/library/xgboost'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.5/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\library" "C:/Users/34F5~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCMgOWd/downloaded_packages/xgboost_0.4-1.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/34F5~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCMgOWd/downloaded_packages/xgboost_0.4-1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

May it be caused by Min-GW 64 installer because I see message that DLL was not created ?

I see this point but dont have an idea how to fix it

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe": line 8: g++ -m32: command not found
```

Comment: Why don't you install the binary instead?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Sorry, I am new to R. I will search for this kind of an installation

Comment: Just don't say `type="source"` and things should work.

Comment: Ie just say  `install.packages("xgboost", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")`

Comment: R version 3.2.5? Why don't you use the latest official R release (3.2.4). Especially for a novice user it is safer than using alpha and beta pre-releases.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install source package on Windows, you need to install **Rtools** first which helps you compile your package. See [this link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to find out which version you should install corresponding to your R version.